# Receiving Notifications in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to send a notification to the user to remind him to do a specific thing using my app at 10AM each day.

My problem is that I am receiving the notification only when I open this app at 10AM. and since then each time I open the app I receive a notification. so if I opened it at 10:03AM I will receive a notification.

here is my MainActivity:

```
public void sendNotification() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);// 10 am
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 03);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0 , intent , 0 ) ;
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent1);
}
```

I am calling my method using `onCreate()` method

AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
</receiver>
```

NotificationReceiver:

```
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "001";
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if( calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.FRIDAY  ) { //  Friday ? dont send a notificatoin : send a notification !
        Intent main_intent = new Intent(context , MainActivity.class) ;
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context , 0, main_intent , 0) ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dropdown)
                .setTicker("some text") // status bar message
                .setContentTitle("some text")
                .setContentText("some text")
                .addAction(R.mipmap.back,"pay Now", pIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    } // END OF FRIDAY CHECK
```

Note: I am also receiving a notification when i install the app for the first time!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do not use `setInexactRepeating` if you want to try to get your app notification at exactly 10am. Use `setRepeating` instead:

```
public void sendNotification() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);// 10 am
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 03);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0 , intent , 0 );
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent1);
}
```

Secondly, another possible issue is, if this problem is occurring on a specific phone (normally phones with aggressive power management like Huawei, Nokia, etc), disable the battery management for that app. These phones are known to be notorious in killing background apps that will also remove it from sending notifications.

Take a look at https://dontkillmyapp.com/

There are solutions for specific phones on there:

Huawei:

Phone Settings > Advanced Settings > Battery Manager > Protected apps – check for your app as Protected

Phone Settings > Apps > Your app > Battery > Power-intensive prompt [x] and Keep running after screen off [x]

Phone settings > Apps > Advanced (At the bottom) > Ignore optimisations > Press Allowed > All apps > Find your app on the list and set to Allow

Phone settings > Battery > App launch and then set your app to “Manage manually” and make sure everything is turned on.

Phone settings > Battery > Launch and then set your app to “Manage manually” and make sure everything is turned on.

For other branded phones, look for something along that line...

Edit:

I just noticed your edit that you get a notification even though installing for the first time. Maybe add on something like this to your calendar:

```
Calendar newDay = Calendar.getInstance();

if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < newDay.getTimeInMillis()) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //add calendar to the next day instead of the time that has passed
    }
```

Comment: I didnt notice I was using setInexactRepeating :) . thanks !

Comment: No problem :-)

I've also adding on an edit after I saw your edit, see if that helps you.

Comment: It works, thanks! basically this is happening because if you set the time at 7 and now it's 8 this notification will be sent (check the documentation). to avoid that we will add one day further! I am just explaining that for those who don't know why we should add one day :)

Comment: If my solution did help with your other issue as well, do mark my answer :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'm using Alarm Manager to send daily local notifications. You should check if you already set the alarm. I'm using a shared preferences on this case.

```
val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
pref?.let {
    if (!pref.getBoolean(BundleParams.AlarmAlreadyRegistered.name, false)) {
        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, TrialNotificationAlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, YOUR_CODE, alarmIntent, 0)

        val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager?

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        }

        manager?.apply {
            setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
            pref.edit().apply {
                putBoolean(BundleParams.AlarmAlreadyRegistered.name, true)

            }.apply()
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'm using a Broad Cast Receiver to listen when phone is restarted to reset the alarm.

```
class DeviceBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context:Context ?, intent:Intent ?){
        intent ?.let {
            if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
                // on device boot complete, reset the alarm
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: are you calling your method using the `onCreate` method? cause I am receiving a notification when I install the app for the first time!

Comment: Yes, I'm calling this onCreate to make sure Alarm is set.